# xsl:number only elements with a certain value

Tags: xml, xslt

I have the following structure

```
<item name="key_1">D</item>
<item name="content_1">Ringo</item>
<item name="key_2">G</item>
<item name="content_2">John</item>
<item name="key_3">G</item>
<item name="content_3">George</item>
<item name="key_4">B</item>
<item name="content_4">Paul</item>
```

I want to transform it into this:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>No.</td>
        <td>Name</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>John</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>George</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I want to take over only elements of type content_n, who's key_n is "G". I don't know how many "G" I have nor where they are in the list.
My problem is the numbering of the resulting table rows. The numbers have to be plain numbers from 1 to the number of "G"-elements. But `<xsl:number count="/item/@[starts-with(name,'key_')]"/>` counts all key_n elements resulting in my example in row numbers "2" and "3". A comparison `<xsl:number count="/item/@[starts-with(name,'key_')]='G'"/>` is not allowed here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply select the items based on the conditions and use `position()` for the number:

```
  <xsl:template match="items">
      <table>
          <thead>
              <tr>
                  <th>No.</th>
                  <th>Name</th>
              </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
              <xsl:apply-templates select="item[@name[starts-with(., 'key_')] and . = 'G']"/>
          </tbody>
      </table>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="item">
      <tr>
          <td>
              <xsl:value-of select="position()"/>
          </td>
          <td>
              <xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::item[1]"/>
          </td>
      </tr>
  </xsl:template>
```

If you want to use xsl:number use the count attribute with the right predicate: `<xsl:number count="item[@name[starts-with(., 'key_')] and . = 'G']"/>`.

Comment: Sorry, my bad.... I meant `xsl:number count=`, not `xsl:number select=` And that is my problem... the right predicate. Because comparisons are not allowed here.

Comment: `<xsl:apply-templates select="item[@name[starts-with(., 'key_')] and . = 'G']"/>` is not alllowed in this select expression.

Comment: I don't see why it shouldn't work, https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/nb9PtDP is the approach using position() and https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/nb9PtDP/1 with xsl:number. Which XSLT processor do you use, can you give the exact error message and a precise code sample? `xsl:number count="/item/@[starts-with(name,'key_')]='G'"/>` is obviously syntactically wrong at the XPath level

Comment: didn't read your count predicate correct. Putting all conditions into the predicate solved it. Thank you!